# Removing rows and columns from MATLAB matrix quickly

Tags: matlab

Is there a fast way to remove rows and columns from a large matrix in MATLAB?

I have a very large (square) distance matrix, that I want to remove a number of rows/columns from.

Naively:

```
s = 12000;
D = rand(s);
cols = sort(randsample(s,2))
rows = sort(randsample(s,2)) 

A = D;
tic
A(rows,:) = [];
A(:,cols) = [];
toc
% Elapsed time is 54.982124 seconds.
```

This is terribly slow though.
Oddly, this *is* the fastest solution suggested at the bottom [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/153352).

An improvement can be made by preallocating the array and using boolean indices

```
A = zeros(size(D) - [numel(rows) numel(cols)]);
r = true(size(D,1),1);
c = true(size(D,2),1);
r(rows) = false;
c(cols) = false;

tic
A = D(r,c);
toc
% Elapsed time is 20.083072 seconds.
```

Is there still a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like a memory bottleneck.  On my feeble laptop, breaking D up and applying these operators to each part was much faster (using s=12,000 crashed my computer).  Here I break it into two pieces, but you can probably find a more optimal partition.

```
s = 8000;
D = rand(s);

D1 = D(1:s/2,:);
D2 = D((s/2 + 1):end,:);

cols = sort(randsample(s,2));
rows = sort(randsample(s,2));

A1 = D1;
A2 = D2;

tic
A1(rows(rows <= s/2),:) = [];
A2(rows(rows > s/2) - s/2,:) = [];
A1(:,cols) = [];
A2(:,cols) = [];
toc

A = D;
tic
A(rows,:) = [];
A(:,cols) = [];
toc

Elapsed time is 2.317080 seconds.
Elapsed time is 140.771632 seconds.
```

Comment: Actually, when I put the splitting and merging inside the tic/toc, it's about twice as slow as the naive approach.

Comment: Not surprising, I should have included that step in the timing.  When you are dealing with data sets this large performance becomes very machine dependent (maybe I should have tested it on something better).

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend on your usage, but I have two ideas:

1. Make it a sparse matrix. The more you're removing the better this option will probably be.
2. Why do you need to remove the values? Could you maybe do:

```
A = D(randsample(s,2), randsample(s,2));
clear D;
% Use A
```

Comment: The problem is that the matrix is by definition *not* sparse. It is a distance matrix, so every entry `[i,j]` is the distance between row `i` and `j` in a dataset. Also, I read that sparse matrices in MATLAB are not optimized for row or column operations, so that might even be slower.  And I actually need to remove the entries, and use only the *remaining* entries.